# Convolution with a constant

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have this variable, u :

$Ix + c = u$

where x and c are two independent random variables and I is a constant.

So I think this is what the convolution is but I am not sure what happens to the constant I. 
$f_u(u)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f_x(u-c)f_c(c) dc$

My imagination tells me that it does not matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the density function of $Ix$ (**very** confusing notation, BTW) can be calculated as very simple [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables):
$$f_{Ix}(y) = \frac1I f_x(y/I).$$
(and this formula has a very obvious intuitive sense)